# How to programmatically scroll the value in a range input bar using Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I want to use Puppeteer to scroll the value left/right in a range input bar, and the html of the element is the following:

```
      <div class="container">
          <span class="bar" style="width: 33.3333%;"></span>
          <input class="rangeInput rangeInput--focused" id="amount" type="range" step="500" max="20000" min="5000" value="10000"></input>
      </div>
```

where the width of the "bar" element adjust for the value selected (notice that the value can only be an integer multiple of 500 that lies in the range). I tried the following 2 approaches:

```
  //Approach 1
       await page.waitForSelector('#amount');
       await page.focus('#amount');
       await page.$eval('#amount', e => e.setAttribute('value', 10000));

  //Approach 2
       await page.waitForSelector('.bar');
       await page.$eval('.bar', e => e.setAttribute('width', "33.3333%"));
```

but neither worked. I am wondering whether someone can propose a workable solution.